# SQL Server tables indexes optimized for sort?

Tags: t-sql, sorting, indexing

I have a stored procedure that inserts rows to an empty table, fresh for each execution. There may be as few as 10 rows and as many as 20,000 rows generated in a given execution. A later step sorts this table. Should I be creating indexes on the Sort keys?

Comment: Why don't you insert it as a sorted list with PK as a running key? It is indexed by primary key now...

Comment: What is your sort by later?  Make that an index, and then just retrieve everything later ORDERed BY that field.

Comment: Joe, the Sort is later because this is part of a complex algorithm where the table is the target of a dynamic Select generated later in the process. The dynamic query has the sort.

Comment: Harsha, please tell me more about what you have in mind. Will adding indexes to this table definition make the sort more efficient?

Comment: Joe, I am making an index on the 4 order by fields. Thanks.